# How can I make this question more measurable without making it too complicated?

Tags: discussion, questions

How can I make this question more measurable, without it becoming more complicated?
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79506/oculus-rift-and-super-resolution

For example a good test could be a character fixed in position in a simple game-world, at a given low resolution, with for simplicity as it might mane a big difference no full screen AA, looking around with mouse-look and asked to describe an object pointed at in the world that is much smaller at the distance it is away from the player than a pixel (block of pixels as part if simulating the low resolution) of the conventional screen.

Then repeating the experiment with the rift and head-look.

However ideally there would be a sample of at least a few people, perhaps different sorts of people as well, for practicality I wanted to use just 1 person.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like what you are asking for is a survey of other people's experiences with a particular visual artifact or effect on particular kinds of hardware.

Unfortunately, this kind of survey question is both too opinion-oriented (since there is no objectively-answerable question) and too broad (since there are an infinite number of "correct" answers, since you are just asking for descriptions of experiences.

That's not the kind of question the StackExchange network is dedicated to collecting. You should probably seek out a discussion forum, such as [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) to ask about this topic.